# Float conditional in bash

Tags: bash

in bash I need to compare two float numbers, one which I define in the script and the other read as paramter, for that I do:

```
   if [[ $aff -gt 0 ]]
    then
            a=b
            echo "xxx "$aff
            #echo $CX $CY $CZ $aff
    fi
```

but I get the error:

[[: -309.585300: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".585300")

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming that you're already familiar with [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: that's like if I tell you that in order to understand human behaviour you just need to be familiar with Schroedinger's equation

Comment: @Dennis: this question requires none of the knowledge in that paper; not *everything* about floats is difficult, and greater/smaller comparisons simply work as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use awk

```
#!/bin/bash
num1=0.3
num2=0.2
if [ -n "$num1" -a -n "$num2" ];then
  result=$(awk -vn1="$num1" -vn2="$num2" 'BEGIN{print (n1>n2)?1:0 }')
  echo $result
  if [ "$result" -eq 1 ];then
   echo "$num1 greater than $num2"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: very nice indeed. one last comment, num1 is read from some file and in some cases it is empty, so the comparison gives weird results. how can in back check somehow "if num1 is empty then num1 = 0" ?

Comment: use `-n` to test for non empty string. see `man test` for more info

Answer (score 8):

Using bc instead of awk:

```
float1='0.43255'
float2='0.801222'

if [[ $(echo "if (${float1} > ${float2}) 1 else 0" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then
   echo "${float1} > ${float2}"
else
   echo "${float1} <= ${float2}"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `test` (which is usually linked to as `[`)and the `bash`-builtin equivalent only support integer numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Use bc to check the math

```
a="1.21231"
b="2.22454" 
c=$(echo "$a < $b" | bc)
if [ $c = '1' ]; then 
    echo 'a is smaller than b'
else 
    echo 'a is larger than b'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use awk for that:

```
e=2.718281828459045
pi=3.141592653589793
if [ "yes" = "$(echo | awk "($e <= $pi) { print \"yes\"; }")" ]; then
    echo "lessthanorequal"
else
    echo "larger"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is this:

```
f1=0.45
f2=0.33
if [[ $f1 > $f2 ]] ; then echo "f1 is greater then f2"; fi
```

which (on OSX) outputs:

```
f1 is greater then f2
```

Here's another example combining floating point and integer arithmetic (you need the great little perl script calc.pl that you can download from [here](http://tucnak.webz.cz/calc01.html)):

```
dateDiff=1.9864
nObs=3
i=1
while [[ $dateDiff > 0 ]] &&  [ $i -le $nObs ]
do
  echo "$dateDiff > 0"
  dateDiff=`calc.pl $dateDiff-0.224`
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Which outputs

```
1.9864 > 0
1.7624 > 0
1.5384 > 0
```

Comment: I just realised that **this doesn't really work because bash ignores the decimal point** silently. It only works in comparing floats for special circumstances, like when they have the same number of digits BEFORE the decimal point. The solution is to either use only the integer part of the floats you are comparing (using -gt instead of > and -lt instead of <; that's good enough for my applications), or split the integer and decimal parts and compare them _as integers_ separately.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necroposting, but looking at @jonretting's already late answer, I thought that the use of `bc` was probably best for concision, although this does not take care of `a` or `b` being empty or undefined:

```
 ( (( $(bc <<< "$a > $b") == 1 )) && echo "a is greater than b") || echo "a is smaller than b"
```

----------
Use `printf "%s\n" [string_to_print]`  instead of `echo [string_to_print]` in a script.